# How do you delete itemrenderers in a spark Listform for mobile?

Tags: apache-flex, memory, itemrenderers

I've got a spark ListForm with a custom mxml itemRenderer,
all the itemRenderer has is:

```
<s:Label text="{data.name}" />
```

When I run the profiler, the listform is not re-using the itemRenderers,
the instances keep going up and up,
I'm using an arrayCollection as the dataprovider.
I even call the dataprovider (arrayCollection) .removeAll() and the
display goes blank, yet the number of instances of the itemRenderer does
not go down. I then run the garbage collector in the profiler, and the
item renderers still stay in memory. How can I remove the itemRenderers from memory?

Comment: Show us your complete renderer; for starters.  I didn't think the top level component of a Spark itemRenderer could be a label.  Also don't use binding; which does odd things; instead listen for the dataChange event and update the text that way.  Also make sure you are using virtualLayouts.  I think that is a property on the layout class.

Comment: Are you by chance using itemRendererFunction?  Prior to Flex 4.6 itemRendererFunction doesn't recycle item renderers.  See the last few slides in this talk for more information: http://flexponential.com/2011/10/05/performance-tuning-mobile-flex-applications/

Answer (score 1):

if you just want a label as an item renderer then in mobile applications it's recommended to use the 
[LabelItemRenderer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/LabelItemRenderer.html)

Answer (score 0):

Set the itemRenderer to null. When GC next runs, the item renderers in memory will be removed.